# C++ cross compile WxWidgets with MXE using CMAKE

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a CMAKE file that allows me to cross compile a WxWidgets application From Ubuntu For Windows.

My tools are all installed correctly, and I am able to run:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc main.cpp $(i686-w64-mingw32.static-wx-config --cxxflags --libs) -o main.exe -std=c++11 -lstdc++
```

and produce a working output.
But I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to convert this into a CMAKE file. Does anyone have any resources or even examples of a working example?

Here is an example of my non-working file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

SET (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(PROJECT_NAME "WxWidgets")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32.static)
project(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  VERSION 1.0
  LANGUAGES CXX)

  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} (i686-w64-mingw32.static-wx-config --cxxflags --libs) -L /home/kevin/wxWidgets/include/ -Wall -std=gnu++2a -static -g")
  
  
  file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.hpp"
        )

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${all_SRCS})
```

I am running the command:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-cmake ..
```

within my build directory.

By removing:

```
**(i686-w64-mingw32.static-wx-config --cxxflags --libs) -L /home/kevin/wxWidgets/include/**
```

...I am getting the error:

```
fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "wx/wxprec.h"
```

I have this file I checked with locate:

```
$ locate wx/wxprec.h
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/wx-3.1/wx/wxprec.h
/home/kevin/wxWidgets/include/wx/wxprec.h
/usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/wxprec.h
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @vre's comment, I have updated my CMakeLists.txt file and have moved closer, it seems now that I just need to link correctly Here is what I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

SET (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(PROJECT_NAME "WxWidgets")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32.static)
project(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  VERSION 1.0)

  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++2a -static -g")
  
  file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.hpp"
        )

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${all_SRCS})

  include( "${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}" )
  find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/wx-3.1/ /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32.static-msw-unicode-static-3.1/)
  target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/)
```

But sadly, I have many linker errors such as:

```
undefined reference to `wxFrame::GetDefaultIcon() const'
```

Comment: `Toolchain.txt` settings maybe??

Comment: It was my down and close vote, because you didn't even bother to show your research, cmake file attempts so far, or any other efforts.  StackOverflow isn't your code & solution shopping mall or help center!

Comment: You need to add a toolchain setting for a C++ compiler, too. You restricted your project to CXX language! But it's better to remove the LANGUAGES option of your project command and use the default which enables C and CXX. And to find wxWidgets you would use find_package(wxWidgets) and add a target_link_libraries and a target_include_directories command.

Comment: @Kevin192291, are you having difficulties building wx or your own code? Which version of wx you are using?

Comment: @Igor, I am having trouble building my own code, I am able to build the WxWidgets Examples with no problem via the terminal. I am using version 3.3.

Comment: The CMake file shouldn't have to contain anything mxe-specific. All of this should come from their toolchain file, added automatically by their CMake wrapper.

Comment: You need `target_link_libraries` command to resolve the undefined references not `target_link_directories` The `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` toolchain setting is still missing.

Comment: See [this part](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux) of CMake docs on what a CMake toolchain file should contain. You may add the settings before your `project` command but it is strongly recommended to have a separate file and add `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<name_of_your_tc_file>` to your cmake command line.

Comment: As for wxWidgets you would do a `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)` followed by 
 `include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})` and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})` see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html?highlight=findwxwidgets) for docs